# Windows service app that can dynamically accept console commands

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-services, console-application

I just wanted some input on a project that I'm working on.  Basically, I'm creating a service that monitors and processes new files in a directory specified by a configuration file and other parameters through the command line.  It should also output text via the command line, i.e. when a user types in '**-help**' it will display it's usage.  A goal is to also make it so that the user can change the configuration file on the fly, so the service will constantly monitor the config file for changes and adjust accordingly.

The challenge I'm seeing is trying to consolidate the ability to enter commands through the command line, display output, as if it were a console app,  and have the service be able process these commands while it is running in the Service Control Manager.  So far in my research, the solutions I've stumbled upon seem to show how to create a Windows Service App that can also run as a console app, but it either operates as one or the other, not both.  Any suggestions or input is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Thank you all for your suggestions, I did some [reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx) on various Windows supported IPC mechanisms.  I boiled my options down to File Mapping, Named Pipes and RPC.  I'm assuming for now that the Windows Service app and Helper Console app will be on the same computer and will not need to communicate over a network.  I'll be looking at Named Pipes first.

Comment: If you wanted to create something where a user could send commands via a command line, you could always have your application listening on a specific port via a tcp client, which you could telnet to, and send commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service needs to offer a possibility to communicate with it, but this can't be done directly, it has to be done by some sort of IPC (inter process communication), this could be .net Remoting, WCF, tcp/ip. You will have to write a helper program that parses the command line and uses this IPC to send the commands to the service, which can act appropiately on receiving it.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a console app that sends requests to the service and displays its responses. If you wanted to be clever, you could include both parts in the same executable. I can't think of any way to make the service write to and read from the console while it's running as a service.